# What do parentheses mean in an #if defined preprocessor operator?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

(I am working on a SDK wherein I have the code of the particular SDK in reference and I am not able to trace out the flow of the program.)

What does

```
#if defined (AR7x00)
```

mean? Specifically, what is the purpose of parentheses in a such a preprocessor operator?

Comment: it adds parentheses around `AR7x00`. Its purpose is preventing madness. If you don't know what a pair of parentheses does in C, then read K&R.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not demonstrate any knowledge of the language being used.

Comment: BTW, `#define` is not a statement, it's a preprocessor directive.

Comment: Even if you call pp directives "statements", it still wouldn't be a define statement, it would be an if statement.

Comment: @H2CO3 yes # define a preprocessor and i wished you gave an answer to my doubt

Comment: I think you are a bit hasty with putting that on hold.  The question might not be well-formed, but it is clear that the function `defined()` is the topic here.  Give it a simple answer, and good is.  No need to close it.

Comment: I guess everybody read the title and not the question. :) This is not a `#define`, it's an `#if defined()`. Since `defined` is not a function (it's a preprocessor *operator*) the parenthesis are not needed.

Comment: @Bathsheba ;-) But at least I'm honest.

Comment: @unwind Indeed, you're right... but it's so annoying when the two don't match.

Comment: @Alfe Not quite: I understand that it's clear what OP is asking -- and he is asking "what doe parentheses do". That kind of question should be answered by reading some introductory material, and not by posting lazily to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've rather precociously edited the question so it could be a reopen candidate.

Comment: @Bathsheba No, it couldn't. The biggest problem with the question is not that it was poorly formulated. The biggest problem is that "what do parentheses do" is a question about fundamental syntax, and thus it is not suited for Stack Overflow. OP should just go ahead and make some effort, read an introductory book and/or a tutorial and learn the basic syntax from there. Stack Overflow is not a "teach me language X" site.

Comment: well i wanted to know in a preprocessor directive, what does the parentheses immediately after #define mean, is it some thing beyond my reach, because i have seen and used #define AR7400 1 which means AR7400 will be replace in code by 1, but the its not the simple preprocessor directive anymore, its like #define (AR7400) and this type of parenthesised naming will give an error as "error: macro names must be identifiers ". so what i suspected "(AR7X00)" is not an identifier but something more. so if anyone understood my doubt and can solve it, i am would be thankful.

Comment: @H2CO3 its not what parentheses do but what parentheses mean in this context #if defined (AR7X00)...

Comment: basically the code is to differentiate two kinds of chip-sets of Atheros namely AR7400 and INT6400, so at an hardware level we can do it by seeing the make but how in c or at higher level of software.

Comment: @TrilokM The parens here don't have special meaning: they do grouping (they modify precedence).

Comment: @H2CO3: They don't affect precedence in this case. The argument to `defined` can only be a single identifier, or a single identifier in parentheses. There is no case in which the parentheses are required (though they can be required for `#if` directives using things other than the `defined` operator).

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, that's true, my first comment was under the (wrong) assumption that the title suggested (namely that OP is writing a `#define` directive), in which case it would normally affect precedence (unless the parenthesis are surrounding the arguments of a function-like macro, of course).

Comment: (*"parentheses", of course, silly me.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These three preprocessor directives:

```
#if defined (AR7x00)

#if defined AR7x00

#ifdef AR7x00
```

all mean exactly the same thing: that the following code is to be processed only if the macro `AR7x00` is currently defined.

The `#ifdef ...` directive is simply a convenient alternative to `#if defined ...`. There's also a `#ifndef ...` directive; `#ifndef FOO` is equivalent to `#if ! defined FOO`.

As for the parentheses, the syntax for the `defined` operator allows for either an identifier, or an identifier in parentheses, with no difference in meaning.  I'm not entirely sure why the parentheses are optional; I suspect it's just historical. (The language reference in the 1978 first edition of [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) doesn't mention the `defined` operator. The second edition shows both forms, with and without parentheses.)

Strictly speaking, these are not grouping parentheses of the kind you see in ordinary expressions; they're specifically part of the syntax of the `defined` operator, which can only be used in preprocessor `#if` directives. In particular, this:

```
#if defined ((AR7x00))
```

is a syntax error.

Comment: thanks for sharing worthy knowledge, but i am trying to change a sdk code to suite my particulars so when i went through the sdk code i find the no where the macro AR7X00 or (AR7X00) for that matter is not defined as such. so is possible that the sdk developers hide these macro definition even from the header files...?

Comment: @TrilokM: It could be predefined by the compiler, perhaps via a command-line option like `-DAR7X00` -- or it might *not* be defined, which is what the `#ifdef` tests.

Comment: thanks. I am working power-line devices which house two kinds of chipsets namely AR7400 and INT6400, asuming the chipsets are predefined by the compiler and should i give the option -DAR7X00 during compilation only..? because the code give an error during compilation.

Comment: You didn't mention a compilation error. Perhaps you should post a new question, since this one has been answered.

Comment: @TrilokM: The line you showed us won't produce that error. `ARX700` and `ARx700` are distinct identifiers. And if you have a question other than the meaning of the parentheses, you should probably post it separately.

Answer (score 5):

I think the parantheses are more important when using multiple conditionals in the preprocessor.  For instance the following conditional expression

```
#if  defined( foo )  || defined( bar )
#error SOME PROBLEM
#endif
```

evaluates differently in my gnu-arm-gcc environment than this one

```
#if defined foo || defined bar
#error SOME PROBLEM
#endif
```

The first example does what I expect, while the other doesn't seem to ever match regardless of if the tokens "foo" and/or "bar" are #defined.

Answer (score 3):

The [gnu.org online docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html) state that you can use `defined` with or without parentheses.

From the [MSDN entry for #if](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx):

> You can also group symbols and operators with parentheses.

The parentheses don't do anything other than group symbols and operators together to modify precedence.

Comment: Neither GNU nor Microsoft defines the C language.

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes, I agree, just pointing out to him different sources of information, so he could get more detail.

Answer (score 2):

C11, 6.10.1 Conditional inclusion, 5:

> Preprocessing directives of the forms
>
> `# ifdef` *identifier new-line group<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> `# ifndef` *identifier new-line group<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> check whether the identifier is or is not currently defined as a macro name. Their conditions are equivalent to `#if defined` *identifier* and `#if !defined` *identifier* respectively.

Here we see that parentheses are not required.